# Clicking button on login page

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, internet-explorer

I'm trying to automate the login at https://www.thewindpower.net/login_en.php and am able to fill out the username and password using:

```
.Text.Value = "xxxxxx"
.Password.Value = "xxxxx"
```

The login button doesn't have an Id.

How can I click the button when the code for it is:

```
<input name="continuer" style="width: 80%; height: 30px;" type="submit" value="Log in">?
```

My VBA code is:

```
Set objIEDoc = objIEApp.Document
With objIEDoc.forms(0)
`        `.Text.Value = "xxxxxxxx"
`        `.Password.Value = "xxxx"
`        `.submit
End with
```

But it doesn't do the click

Comment: How about the issue? Is my answer below helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element by `name="continuer"` like this `objIEDoc.getElementsByName("continuer")(0).Click`.

The following sample code works, you can have a try:

```
Sub OpenIE()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://www.thewindpower.net/login_en.php"
    Do Until ie.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
    
Set objIEDoc = ie.document
With objIEDoc
     .getElementsByName("login")(0).Value = "name"
     .getElementsByName("passw")(0).Value = "passw"
     .getElementsByName("continuer")(0).Click
End With

End Sub
```